# Как скрыть элементы в twig?

Tags: php, веб-программирование, twig

Нужно скрыть элементы, у которых в `data-value` год меньше текущего, как это можно сделать. В php не очень силен. Желательно сделать внутри вызова. `value` подставляет год

```
{% for value, string in form.ccYear %}
     <a href="#" data-value="{{ value }}">{{ string }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```twig
{% for value, string in form.ccYear %}
    {% if value >= "now"|date("Y") %}
        <a href="#" data-value="{{ value }}">{{ string }}</a>
    {% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```